Count the number of lines with at least one value, for each value
I have a dataframe:
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3"),
                 col2 = c("value_2", "value_2", "value_4"),
                 col3 = c("value_1", "value_3", "value_3")
)

I want to count the number of lines in which a value appears at least once.
In my application there are lot more values and columns so using ifelse() for each value would be too time consumming,
The dedired output is:
df_out = data.frame(value_1 = c(1),
                    value_2 = c(2),
                    value_3 = c(2),
                    value_4 = c(1)
)

If possible, I'd rather use only base R or Tidyverse packages.

Here is one method using the tidyverse...
df %>% mutate(rowno = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowno) %>% 
  group_by(value) %>% 
  summarise(n = n_distinct(rowno))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  value       n
  <chr>   <int>
1 value_1     1
2 value_2     2
3 value_3     2
4 value_4     1


Another base-R option:
df |>
  apply(1, unique, simplify = FALSE) |>
  unlist() |>
  table() |>
  as.data.frame()


#      Var1 Freq
# 1 value_1    1
# 2 value_2    2
# 3 value_3    2
# 4 value_4    1


With reschape from base:
> reshape(df, 
+         ids = rownames(df), 
+         direction = "long", 
+         varying = names(df)[1:3], 
+         v.names = "values") |>
+   aggregate(cbind(n = id) ~ values, data = _, \(x) length(unique(x)))
   values n
1 value_1 1
2 value_2 2
3 value_3 2
4 value_4 1

